# What's going wrong with my python logic?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to create a directory editor for a warehouse managing project, but every time I try to create a new folder that has already been created, rather than handling the problem like I specify in the elif block it gives me this error :

```
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:/Users/User_Name/Documents/Warehouse_Storage/folder_name'
```

As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with the base logic of my if statement.

Here's my code:

```
if operation.lower() == "addf" :

    name = input("What would you like to name your new folder? \n")

    for c in directory_items :
        if name != c :
            os.makedirs(path + name + "/")
            operation_chooserD()

        elif name == c:
            print("You already created a folder with this name.")
            operation_chooserD()
```

Comment: You need to check **all** `directory_items` first. It's not because the **first** one is not equal, that the **second** (or any other) cannot be equal.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your logic:

- Attempting to create the new item for **every** item in the directory
- The if/elif test is redundant

What you really want to do is something like:

```
if c not in directory_items:
    os.makedirs(path + name + "/")
    operation_chooserD()

else: 
    print("You already created a folder with this name.")
    operation_chooserD()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the directory items - if there's a folder with a different name than `name`, you'll enter the `if` branch, even if there's also a folder with that name.

The best solution here, IMHO, is to not reinvent the wheel, and let python check if the folder exists for you:

```
folder = path + name + "/"

if os.path.exists(folder):
    print("You already created a folder with this name.")
else:
    os.makedirs(folder)

operation_chooserD()
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be comparing your new name to every item in the directory, this will definitely hit the name!=c condition (several times). In this case the loop is unnecesary.

YOu can try something along the line of.

```
if name in c:
//do stuff if name exists
else:
//create the directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess directory_items is list of file names in current directory.

```
if operation.lower() == "addf" :

    name = input("What would you like to name your new folder? \n")
    print(directory_items)
    # check here what you are getting in this list, means directory with / or not. If you are getting
    if name not in directory_items:
        os.makedirs(path + name + "/")
        operation_chooserD()
    else:
        print("You already created a folder with this name.")
        operation_chooserD()
```